# Simple ASP.Net Deployment query

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web

Sorry if this question is too simple but I have not been able to find a solid answer anywhere yet.

So I have a ASP.NET Web application, Which is consisted of some Webpages (ASPX files) and also some business libraries(dlls, made with VB.NET). These vb.Net Dlls are used by webpages.

I have a local IIS and everything compiles/runs good on my computer.

Now I changed code in one of these webpages and also on VB.NET files(dlls).

After this I made a build with no errors.

I want to know if I can just copy this changed  ASPX page and VB.NET dll to the webserver(on different machine). This webserver already has all of the needed files for this application but only this one APSX page and VB.NRT Dll need to be updated.

Comment: short answer : should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already hosted the application in IIS of other machine and just want to update (copy new files and paste in web server directory) some files then you just need to updated those `dlls` and `aspx` pages. It will take effect.

Comment: Ok thanks. so just to confirm , all I need to copy 4 files to the destination webserver?

MyChangedPage.Aspx,MyChangedPage.Aspx.vb, MyChangedPage.Aspx.resx
And MyChange.dll ?

Comment: Replace whatever has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace. 
It will take effect.

Remember to change the connection string if required.